# self.tableView.reloadData() not reloading

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableViewController which works fine with TableViewCell:

> class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

However I want to implement a method to update and reload the data in the TableView.
The update part works well, it deletes CoreData objects, queries HealthKit, saves to CoreData and then call a function (func setupArrays) in TableViewController which fetch data from CoreData and appends it to arrays used in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  From the Console log I can see that it works well(e.g. the updated arrays reflects changes in Healthkit).  The problem arises when I try to reload the tableView:

> self.tableView.reloadData()

nothing happens !

I did some research and also tried this method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Still nothing.

I call the reloadData function at the end of the function setupArrays.  (This is also the place where I print to the log the arrays which correctly reflect changes):

```
func setupArrays (){

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("stepsSwitch") == true {
        titleArray.append(stepsCell.title())
        imageNameArray.append(stepsCell.imageName)
        xAxisDatesArray.append(cdFetchSteps.queryCoreDataDate())
        yAxisValuesArray.append(cdFetchSteps.queryCoreDataData())

    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hrSwitch") == true {
        titleArray.append(heartRateCell.title())
        imageNameArray.append(heartRateCell.imageName)
        xAxisDatesArray.append(cdFetchHeartRate.queryCoreDataDate())
        yAxisValuesArray.append(cdFetchHeartRate.queryCoreDataData())

    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("weightSwitch") == true {

        titleArray.append(weightCell.title())
        imageNameArray.append(weightCell.imageName)
        xAxisDatesArray.append(cdFetchWeight.queryCoreDataDate())
        yAxisValuesArray.append(cdFetchWeight.queryCoreDataData())

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    println(yAxisValuesArray)
}
```

Both delegate and dataSource is set correctly in the IB.  I tried to add them "explicitly" in the class e.g.:

> class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

But that did nothing.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titleArray.count
    }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TableViewCell

    myCell.title.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    myCell.imageName =  imageNameArray[indexPath.row]
    myCell.xAxisDates = xAxisDatesArray[indexPath.row] 
    myCell.yAxisValues = yAxisValuesArray[indexPath.row] 

    return myCell    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

when I put a breakpoint cellForRowAtIndexPath it shows the values for title and imageName, but appears empty for xAxisDates and xAxisValues both at the first load and after reload (see attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vncgb.png)).  This seems strange to me as the values are available in the TableViewCell and displays fine.  Are arrays not visible in the debug area/variables view ?

**Question:  How do I update my TableViewController?**

Any help would be very much welcomed - thank you.

Comment: Use [tableView reloadData].

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, no change, no error

Comment: If I use code:   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            [tableView.reloadData]
        })
    I get errors: 1) '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'reloadData'
   2) Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: Please show your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods

Comment: Have you printed `titleArray` before the reload? Does it differ from what is shown? How?

Comment: I am not sure what printed means, but yes all the arrays that are called in cellForRowAtIndexPath have already been "printed" in the sense that the TableViewController has loaded and shows the data on the simulator. It just doesn't re-load the arrays to re-create the cells with the new data, even though the arrays themselves are updated.  It is as if either the reloadData() does not work, or that tableView remembers in "flash storage" old values and don't bother to RELoadData.

Comment: put a breakpoint to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and see if it has been called after `reloadData` function is called. if yes check data for each row.

Comment: @ersin-sezgin thanks, question is updated with screenshot from debug area

Comment: What you are telling is confused me. You have no data at all in your tableviewcells and yet previously on your question you mentioned that you can see correct values before reload. Are you sure you are using dynamic cells?

Comment: I can see the xAxisDates and yAxisValues in the TableViewCell which creates a chart correctly, the only place where that data comes from is  via cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I am not sure why it is not visible at the breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  The xAxisDates and yAxisValues data comes from CoreData, whereas the title and image are static values, maybe that has something to do with why xAxisDates and yAxisValues are not visible?